# knex.js with pgbouncer

Tags: knex.js, pgbouncer

I am looking at implementing pgbouncer.  We are using knex.js in our node app and as far as I can tell there is no way to disable it's built in connection pooling.  What would be the best option for handling this?

Comment: If your app has built-in pooling, why implement pgbouncer?

Comment: The internal pooler doesn't work as well scaling this out.  I want a shared pooler across servers which is where pgbouncer comes in.